# How to check if at least one string is contained in another with AssertJ?

Tags: java, assert, assertion, assertj

I would like to check if at least one string is contained in another using AssertJ.

For example, having:

```
String actual = "I am a string";
String oneString = "am";
String anotherString = "some string";
```

Currently I can write:

```
assertThat(actual.contains(oneString) || actual.contains(anotherString)).isTrue();
```

so if one of the two conditions is true, the assertion will pass. However, in case of failures, there is no detail on what failed exactly.

What would be a good way to achieve this check and have specific details when failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AssertJ 3.21.0, [`containsAnyOf`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractCharSequenceAssert.html#containsAnyOf(java.lang.CharSequence...)) is available:

```
String actual = "I am a string";
String oneString = "am";
String anotherString = "some string";

assertThat(actual).containsAnyOf(oneString, anotherString);
```

---

Since AssertJ 3.12.0, [`satisfiesAnyOf`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#satisfiesAnyOf(java.util.function.Consumer...)) can be used to check if at least one string is contained in `actual`:

```
String actual = "I am a string";
String oneString = "am";
String anotherString = "some string";

assertThat(actual).satisfiesAnyOf(s -> assertThat(s).contains(oneString),
                                  s -> assertThat(s).contains(anotherString));
```

Comment: assertThat(Arrays.asList("abc.efg")).containsAnyOf("abc", "d");  it's failed...don't understand,please help!

Comment: assertThat(actual.contains(oneString)||actual.contains(anotherString)).isTrue();   i tink this will work for me ,but when it failed ,i can't see the string detail when it throw Exception

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your example. How is `actual` declared?

Comment: just String, like "i am string"  ,assertThat(Arrays.asList("i am string")).containsAnyOf("am", "somestring");

Comment: Got it, then my answer is wrong because you are looking for string assertions and not collection assertions. I will update it.

Comment: I updated my answer and I raised https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2303 for a possible improvement.

Comment: Thank you very much bro, what you did is really admirable

Comment: No problem, and feel free to accept my answer if that helped :-)